# C# How to to tell what process is using a file?

Tags: c#

I am getting a pretty common, "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Now I am nearly certain that the only process accessing this file is from code that I have written and I've been careful to use a using statement around accessing it.

But to be 100% sure, is there anyway to check this programatically when this error occurs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also a small tool handle.exe in [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) that does exactly what you need. Use it from the command line:

```
handle.exe -a <filename>
```

Of course under Vista and Windows 7 this tool must be run elevated.

Comment: Of course, this isn't a "programmatic" check, it's a separate command-line tool.  But those can be automated too.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. oh.exe from the Resource Kit and Process Explorer from sysInternals both show who is using what

Both of them use techniques not available in C#.

Comment: Unavailable in c#, even with unsafe, win32 calls and interop?

Comment: There are several things that can't be done with C# (even with the advanced techniques mentioned), among which are driver development and DLL injection.  However it seems that getting the list of handles is available in a user-mode API, ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation), which it should be possible to p/invoke.  It's Process Monitor which has functionality that cannot be duplicated using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Vista adds a new function, [GetRunningObjectTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684004%28VS.85%29.aspx) which you can use to detect which program has a file open. This only works in Vista+, and it only works when the application that has the file open actually implements supports for `IFileIsInUse` (e.g. Office supports it, but most 3rd-party apps probably don't).

Other than that, the usual way this is implemented is by opening each process, enumerating the file handles they have open and searching for the filename in question. This is pretty low-level, and would require quite a bit of P/Invoke to implement in C#, but it's not impossible.

It's usually easy enough just to open up Process Explorer and let it do the search.